# Android: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(UserTable, null, 
                "UserName=?", new String[] {username}, 
                null, null, AccessedDate);
```

I am getting this no column found exception when i am trying to open my activity. The error points to the above`query line`.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.text.sample/com.text.sample.usercontext.RecentsActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: UserName
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE UserName=?
>   ORDER BY AccessedDate     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)      at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: UserName
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE UserName=?
>   ORDER BY AccessedDate     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588) 
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58) 
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37) 
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
>     at com.text.sample.common.DAL.getAllPatients(DAL.java:104)      at
>   com.text.sample.usercontext.RecentsActivity.onCreate(RecentsActivity.java:38)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>     ... 11 more

Comment: Are you sure the column is there? Also, you are referencing a variable  named `UserTable`, but it's selecting from the `Patient` table. Is that correct?

Comment: @JoeF: its referencing to the the Patient DB, the variable UserTable holds Patient DB value.

Comment: Are you sure UserName are spelled the same in your table?

Comment: Is there anyway i can delete the database manually.

Comment: Just clear the data in your device

Comment: @HoanNguyen: i am checking this in emulator, closing and re-opening the emulator should work right... even that clears the data right.

Comment: No in the emulator there is an option like wipe user data check that or create another virtual device and then make sure that you have the option to ask on launch

Comment: Create another virtual device and when you do I think there is an option to wipe the user data, check that. In your project right click Properties --> Run/Debug Settings --> Edit --> Target and check the Always prompt to pick device and when run pick your new virtual device

Comment: You can also choose to run sql query to delete the whole table : db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause of "I'm sure the column is there", but "no such column" is returned, 
would be your database previously has another format being installed, and you updated it without incrementing  your db version, and using onUpgrade to update your database.

If this matches your case, kindly have a look at this post, it teaches you how to perform onUpgrade correctly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14579351/1131470

Answer (score 0):

I guess naming the column as a constant should help.. this is one of the most common mistakes so instead of remembering name of each column why not place in constants class or columns class as static final member and then access it

It will be some thing like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(UserTable, null, 
            UserColumn.USER_NAME + "=?", new String[] {username}, 
            null, null, UserColumn.ACCESSED_DATE);
```

this will give you more control and weed out silly mistakes.