# Error Inserting and table not found

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I tried to do a query to the android sqlite database to create table and insert data to database.

create table function

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_ID_USER + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_NAMA + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_REGID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DIBUAT_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }
```

inserting data function

```
public void addUser(String id_user, String name, String email, String regid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAMA, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_ID_USER, id_user);
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_REGID, regid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_DIBUAT_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

I think this code is right but his contain error will i run

```
05-05 11:19:15.549: E/SQLiteDatabase(29294): Error inserting regid=XX1 id_user=12 nama=Edwin Andrianto dibuat_at=2013-05-01 15:11:41 email=edwinuad@gmail.com

05-05 11:19:15.549: E/SQLiteDatabase(29294): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table login has no column named id_user: , while compiling: INSERT INTO login(regid,id_user,nama,dibuat_at,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Has anyone any idea about what is wrong in the above syntax? Thank you

Full code DatabaseHandler.java

```
package net.drieanto.lagidimana.library;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ID_USER = "id_user";
    private static final String KEY_NAMA = "nama";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_REGID = "regid";
    private static final String KEY_DIBUAT_AT = "dibuat_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_ID_USER + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_NAMA + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_REGID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DIBUAT_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String id_user, String name, String email, String regid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAMA, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_ID_USER, id_user);
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_REGID, regid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_DIBUAT_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("id_user", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("regid", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("dibuat_at", cursor.getString(5));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: **table login has no column named id_user** it says everything

Comment: Where's the bit where you set the value of KEY_ID_USER?  Look there for your problem.

Comment: are key_id_user and id_user are the same?

Comment: in variabel private static final String KEY_ID_USER = "id_user";

Comment: if i no use KEY_ID_USER the program no probleme but if i use KEY_ID_USER it have error

Comment: i am modified from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: clear your data using System menu in your device

Comment: yes fix thank's @HoanNguyen

Comment: Every time you modify your table you have to do the above since SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate is only called the first time the database was created. By clearing the data you delete the database, thus onCreate is called again.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens if you are editing this part of codes from time to time

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
    + KEY_ID_USER + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_NAMA + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
    + KEY_REGID + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_DIBUAT_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
```

without using proper onUpgrade function. A simple clear data or reinstall could fix the problem but for a cleaner and proper solution please refer to:
[SQLite onUpgrade()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579175/sqlite-onupgrade/14579351#14579351)

Please understand that in a world without Unicorns your users will not likely do a reinstallation like you did. Reinstalling should really be stop suggested as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `table login has no column named id_user` already tell the reason.

First, to confirm the issue , you should/could use `sqlite3` to check the database schema:

```
sqlite3 /data/data/your.package/databases/xxx.db
>.schema YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```

If there was no such column called `id_user`, simply delete the database and reinstall your apps should fix the issue.