# When providing an upgrade for your android app on the playstore, can one run code'/tasks on your locally saved data?

Tags: java, android, google-play

So I was wondering about using http://www.mapdb.org as the storage mechanism for my app
(because I believe that it represents the future of the data layer for java, but I digress).

However it doesn't yet support schema evolution. So in the interim, changing fields of the persisted classes would cause it to break. It's not possible for the upgraded app to update the data as it would already ship with the new version of the classes.

What I need is a hook, trigger for when the update happens, that the old version can output the data in a temporary format (xstream xml), so that the new version can continue along happily. Does the playstore support anything like this?

Questions like this 
[SQLite onUpgrade()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579175/sqlite-onupgrade)
seem to suggest there is an onUpgrade, but because at that point the schema of classes have broken, it's too late I would think. If I provide my own in-app preparation, there is nothing to guarantee this would run before the playstore upgrade mechanism would run.

**Update**: I realize that the onUpgrade was a sqlite thing, and not an android thing in the referenced question. My mistake

Also just to stress, this question refers to an object database, where the serialized version of the class is important, and it doesn't yet support schema evolution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `SharedPreferences` to store the version of the app at the last launch, and compare that to the current app version. If the last version stored in your SharedPreferences is older than the current version, you can perform your upgrade tasks.

You can check your app version with

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = activity.getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(), 0);
int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
```

Your code might end up looking something like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int lastVersion = prefs.getInt("lastVersion", -1);
if (lastVersion != -1 && lastVersion  < versionCode) {
    // Perform update logic
    prefs.edit().putInt("lastVersion", versionCode).commit();
}
```

You can of course also check the old version for a specific number, so if the upgrade from version 15 of your app to version 18 requires a specific set of tasks, you can perform those.

Comment: At that point it is already too late. See my comment on the question above.

Comment: Why is it too late? You can perform SQLite queries to update column names or content. There shouldn't be anything you _can't_ do with this method or with `onUpgrade()`.

Comment: It's not sqlite, it's mapdb. It's an object database.

Comment: Ah, I see. I would recommend not storing serialiazed objects, but rather store the fields you need. Instead of writing an entire object into one cell of one row, write each field of the Object into a field in the database. It will make your code far more able to adapt to changes. I don't have any experience with map DB, but it sound like you want true SQLite.

Comment: At some point schema evolution will be added to mapdb as functionality, maybe at a slightly higher level. However databases like neodatis are now unsupported and I want to go with an apache licensed object database. The data is sufficiently complex that pulling out fields of something that is kinda graph-like is not feasible. Mapdb operates at speeds that are kinda ridiculous and looks like the future.

Answer (score 0):

What is unclear about the SQLite onUpgrade action and steps outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14579351/1916341) ?

The schema changed, you know what the changes are, so you write the SQL (probably raw SQL) to modify the table (add/remove columns, and fill in the new columns) etc as needed.

Unsure what you mean about "classes have changed" unless you're referring to de-serializing things out of the DB, in which case: a) you still have access to the old classes, b) you know what the new ones look like, so as above, you write the code to move data from old to new.

The only problem I've had is trying to add a column with a "not null" constraint, since sqlite won't let you do that (ie you'd create a column with null values by altering the table, therefore violating the constraint). (I removed the constraint, but maybe a more complex alter table statement with update as well would have worked)

Comment: The deserializing is exactly the point. It's an object database, so if the classes have changed it can't yet cope. So that would mean either dynamically loading both sets of classes one at a time (so they don't conflict)... or I need a way of serializing at a particular point before the upgrade. Manipulating the bits to cater for changes in schema is not feasible for me to implement, and will have to wait for such solutions to emerge. Hence the question.

Comment: One thing you've made clear is the onUpgrade I was looking at was a sqlite thing, not an android thing. thanx for that.

Comment: How many version changes are you looking at doing/supporting ? (ie is there a "you will lose all data" option on upgrade, or will you always support any/all upgrades ?) You will always know the name of the objects, and if the naming matters (depending on how you serialize/deserialize out), you may need to start naming your objects with versions, and dragging a lot of cruft around solely for being able to access the old objects to do whatever changes are needed for an upgrade.

Comment: Those are difficult questions to answer at this point. We can see various solutions. To some extent we can back up stuff to the cloud, but we can't guarantee that the user will see the "warning" if they upgrade through the marketplace (uncertain)!? Naming classes with versions is undesirable.